# Sending object from thymeleaf template to Rest Controller returns "Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: spring, utf-8, thymeleaf

I'm trying to POST some object fields to a RestController using thymeleaf.

But the result of the post returns what looks like a parsing error :

> There was an unexpected error (type=Unsupported Media Type, status=415). Content type
>   'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported

The index page sends two attributes to the controller which then calls the business service that builds the new object.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Simple Sidebar - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link th:href="@{/index/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
    rel="stylesheet">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link th:href="@{/index/css/simple-sidebar.css}" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form action="#" th:action="@{/accounts}" th:object="${account}" method="post" enctype="application/json">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                            <label for="inputState">Departement</label>
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{owner}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Type in the department ..." />
                            </div>
                    </div>  
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4 ">
                            <label for="inputState">Budget</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" th:field="*{budget}"  class="form-control" placeholder="Type in Budget ..." />
                            </div>
                    </div>
                    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Enregistrer</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->

</body>
</html>
```

This is the Rest Controller :

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@RequestMapping(value="/accounts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void addAccount(@RequestBody Account account ) {
    accountService.addAccount(account);
}

}
```

Account is a simple POJO :

```
public class Account {


private String id;
private String owner;
private double budget;
private double budgetInvest;
private double budgetFonction;

public Account() {

}

public Account(String id,String owner, double budget, double budgetInvest, double budgetFonction 
        ) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.owner=owner;
    this.budget = budget;
    this.budgetInvest = budgetInvest;
    this.budgetFonction = budgetFonction;
}

public Account (String owner, double budget) {
    this.owner = owner;
    this.budget=budget;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public double getBudget() {
    return budget;
}

public void setBudget(double budget) {
    this.budget = budget;
}

public double getBudgetInvest() {
    return budgetInvest;
}

public void setBudgetInvest(double budgetInvest) {
    this.budgetInvest = budgetInvest;
}

public double getBudgetFonction() {
    return budgetFonction;
}

public void setBudgetFonction(double budgetFonction) {
    this.budgetFonction = budgetFonction;
}

public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}

public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}




}
```

And the add method simply adds the object to a list of objects.

What am i doing wrong here ?

Comment: I think that you mix RestController and Controller. You should use a Controller here.

Comment: Why ? Shouldn't it be possible for a RestController to receive data from an html form ?

Comment: @FeatherAndInk Are you doing two separate project for backend and frontend ? Or in a single project ?

Comment: Single project, the frontend is loaded through template folder which calls the static ressources.

Comment: @FeatherAndInk After creating account in which page you want to redirect ?
Please give a screenshot of your project structure ?

Comment: First I want to receive the POSTed data with the RestController which will call the business services then for redirecting I use a normal Controller class that solves requests. But for now I just want to make sure that my RestController can receive the data from an HTML page. I will post a screen as soon as I'll have my workstation in hands.

Comment: @FeatherAndInk Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think problem in you controller. First it won't be `@RestController`. It will be `@Controller`. Second it won't be `@RequestBody`. It will be `@ModelAttribute`.So write your controller like

```
@Controller
public class AccountController {

@Autowired
private AccountService accountService;

@RequestMapping(value="/accounts", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void addAccount(@ModelAttribute("account") Account account ) {
   System.out.ptintln("Checking");
    accountService.addAccount(account);
}
```

`The most relevant to the discussion of REST, the @RestController annota- tion tells Spring that all handler methods in the controller should have their return value written directly to the body of the response, rather than being carried in the model to a view for rendering.` This line from book `spring in action`. So here you should use `@Controller` annotation.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but I was away from my computer at the time. So I tried to convert my RestController to a Controller as you both proposed, and indeed everything works pretty fine, and this is the way to go at least for the simple workflow i'm trying to implement here. Although I would like to ask are RestController unable to communicate with html pages ?

Answer (score -1):

You can use restcontroller but u must using ajax post for run "/account"

Cmiiw