# Post request work on postman but not in browser (CodeStatus : 415) - SpringBoot, thymeleaf

Tags: spring-boot, forms, post, postman, thymeleaf

It's a bit a shame but I just started with front end developping.

My Problem : I have a html page with a form and the submission requestbody is not transfered to the back end.

I'm using spring boot, spring security, thymeleaf.

Here the Controller :

RegistrationController java class

```
package my.package;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    @PostMapping
    public  String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request){

        registrationService.register(request);

        return "Registration need to be confirmed";
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token") String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }

}
```

With PostMan the request works as a Post request with the body as json:

```
{
    "firstName": "firstName",
    "lastName": "lastName",
    "email": "firstName.lastName@gmail.com",
    "password": "password"
}
```

But when I implement the html page as following :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>registration page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
                    <form th:action="@{/registration}" method="post">
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="email" name="email"  id="email">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                        </div>
                    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and fill the formular and press submit the business services dont succeed : got 415 status error

With DevTools i see the Payload nicely filled

I do not understand why the @RequestBody don't get filled with the payload data. Maybe the problem is somewhere else.
I don't understand why in postman the request works but not in the browser

Thank you for all the help you can bring

Alex

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54065603/sending-object-from-thymeleaf-template-to-rest-controller-returns-unsupported-m

Comment: Thank you for the link, seams to be clear now that @RequestBody don't work with form payload data. Need to review my back end a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Instead, make an AJAX call on form submit.
make sure your form has an ID

```
<form id="form-id" method="post">


$( document ).ready(function() {
// SUBMIT FORM
$("#form-id").submit(function(event) {
    // Prevent the form from submitting via the browser.
    event.preventDefault();
    ajaxPost();
});


function ajaxPost(){
    
    // PREPARE FORM DATA
    var formData = {
        firstname : $("#firstName").val(),
        lastname :  $("#lastName").val(),
        --------other attributes with values---------
    }
    
    // DO POST
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        contentType : "application/json",
        url : "/registration",
        data : JSON.stringify(formData),
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(result) {
            ----redirect to another url----
            console.log(result);
        },
        error : function(e) {
            alert("Error!")
            console.log("ERROR: ", e);
        }
    });
    
    // Reset FormData after Posting
    resetData();

}

function resetData(){
    $("#firstname").val("");
    $("#lastname").val("");
}
```

})